# SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'checkConnectivityRequest' property

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I am using the `COLT (ISP) WSDL` in `PHP (Laravel)`, I have created all the objects using `WSDL2PHPGENERATOR`, and imported these into my project.

The XML which works via SOAPUI is the following:

```
<soapenv:Envelopexmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v5="http://www.colt.net/xml/ns/b2bFramework/v5" xmlns:con="http://aat.colt.com/connectivityservice">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v5:checkConnectivity>
         <checkConnectivityRequest>
            <con:checkConnectivityRequest con:schemaVersion="5.0">
               <con:requestType>ALL</con:requestType>
               <con:requestMode>
                  <con:requestID>123</con:requestID>
                  <con:siteAddress>
                     <con:premisesNumber>16</con:premisesNumber>
                     <con:streetName>Rue Friant</con:streetName>
                     <con:cityTown>Paris</con:cityTown>
                     <con:postalZipCode>75014</con:postalZipCode>
                     <con:coltOperatingCountry>France</con:coltOperatingCountry>
                     <con:requiredProduct>Colt Voice Line (v)</con:requiredProduct>
                     <con:isConvergedVL>false</con:isConvergedVL>
                     <con:connectivityType>ALL</con:connectivityType>
                  </con:siteAddress>
               </con:requestMode>
            </con:checkConnectivityRequest>
         </checkConnectivityRequest>
      </v5:checkConnectivity>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My PHP Code is the following:

```php
    $request_id = 1123123;
    $Connectivity_Type = \App\Classes\WSDLs\COLT\Connectivity_Type::COLTFibre;
    $LocationAddress_Type = new \App\Classes\WSDLs\COLT\LocationAddress_Type(array($Connectivity_Type));
    $LocationAddress_Type->PremisesNumber = 1;
    $LocationAddress_Type->StreetName = "Whittington Avenue";
    $LocationAddress_Type->CityTown = "London";
    $LocationAddress_Type->PostalZipCode = "EC3V 1PJ";
    $LocationAddress_Type->ColtOperatingCountry = \App\Classes\WSDLs\COLT\coltOperatingCountry::UnitedKingdom;
    $LocationAddress_Type->RequiredProduct = \App\Classes\WSDLs\COLT\RequiredProduct_Type::ColtIPAccess;
    $requestMode = new \App\Classes\WSDLs\COLT\RequestMode_Type($request_id, array($LocationAddress_Type));
    $Request_Type = \App\Classes\WSDLs\COLT\Request_Type::SITE;
    $schemaVersion = 5.0;
    $checkConnectivityRequest = new \App\Classes\WSDLs\COLT\checkConnectivityRequest($Request_Type, $requestMode, $schemaVersion);
    $checkConnectivity = new  \App\Classes\WSDLs\COLT\checkConnectivity();
    $checkConnectivity->setCheckConnectivityRequest($checkConnectivityRequest);

    Log::info(array($checkConnectivity));
    //return "Check Log";
    try{ 
        $a = new \App\Classes\WSDLs\COLT\ColtB2bFrameworkcommonwebSvcProviderb2bFramework_v5(array(
          "exceptions" => 0, 
          "trace" => 1, 
          'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
          'login' => config('mike.COLT_API_USERNAME'),
          'password' =>  config('mike.COLT_API_PASSWORD'),
      ));
      //return var_dump($a->__getTypes());
      $response = $a->checkConnectivity($checkConnectivity);
```

However when getting this working it comes back with the error:

> SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'checkConnectivityRequest'
>   property

It won't even show last request etc in order to debug.

I wonder whether it is something do do with the XML having two 
  Layers.

Have I missed something?

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who runs across this in future. I updated to a newer version of their WSDL, and it started working, it was clearly an error in that.

However not so much that it didnt work in SOAPUI.

If you encounter this. It may be worth just querying the Data Directly rather than using a soap client in PHP.